# CSS: Adding padding to a background image

Tags: css

I need to add padding to a class with a background image.  However, when I do so, the padding isn't added to the background image, just the anchor.  What am I doing wrong?  Here's my CSS:

```
.heart {
    width:200px;
    height:18px;
    background:url(/images/content/digital-learning/course-library/sprite-favorites.png) 0px 18px repeat-y;
    padding-left: 20px;
    display:block;
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try using `margin-left: 20px;` instead.

`Margin` is outside the container and `padding` is inside the container, so padding won't move the background of the container.

Answer (score 0):

Background can show based on `background-origin: content-box;`

```css
.heart {
  width: 200px;
  height: 18px;
  border: 1px solid tomato;
  background: url('https://via.placeholder.com/50x100') left center repeat-y;
  padding-left: 20px;
  display: block;
  background-origin: content-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="heart">x</div>
</div>
```

**or**

Another solution is `background-position-x: 20px;`

```css
.heart {
  width: 200px;
  height: 18px;
  border: 1px solid tomato;
  background-image: url('https://via.placeholder.com/50x100');
  padding-left: 20px;
  display: block;
  background-position-x: 20px;
  background-repeat: repeat-y
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="heart">x</div>
</div>
```